# Custom Toolbar design

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm building a custom toolbar for search activity and it's suitable in some devices and not suitable in other screens . 
i tried it on my device 720*1280 and it's fine . but when i open app on genymotion device 768*1280 it appears like that . 
[image]

search_toolbar.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar_bg"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="back"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".99"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorHint="#FFCEC9C9"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Search.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/search_page_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/search_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify you `Search.xml` like this (Remember add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your recyclerview):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar_bg"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="back"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".99"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorHint="#FFCEC9C9"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/search_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp" 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thanks , working fine . but why i couldn't use include ??

Comment: If you want to include `search_toolbar.xml`. You need put only toolbar to your `search_toolbar.xml`, not the whole `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"` in `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Use this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar. Hope it is your solution.